# Query for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following input tables:

**table_1**

| tid | name | pic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | XXX |
| 2 | name2 | ZZZ |
| 3 | name3 | YYY |

**table_2**

| fid | fname | tid | desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd1 | 1 | File1 |
| 2 | abcd2 | 1 | File2 |
| 3 | xyze3 | 2 | File1 |

I want to show "*table_2.desc"* as a field and the value is "yes" or "no" based on if "*tid*" have "*desc*" with data "File1" (so "File1" will be "Yes").

**Expected Output**:

| tid | name | pic | File1 | File2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | XXX | Yes | Yes |
| 2 | name2 | ZZZ | Yes | No |
| 3 | name3 | YYY | No | No |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a left join with aggregation we can try:

```sql
SELECT t1.tid, t1.name, t1.pic,
       CASE WHEN SUM(t2.`desc` = 'File1') > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS File1,
       CASE WHEN SUM(t2.`desc` = 'File2') > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS File2
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t2.tid = t1.tid
GROUP BY t1.tid, t1.name, t1.pic;
```